# Alt key not functioning as expected. How to change Level 3 Shift key back to Alt key?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

### The problem

After a recent automatic update I noticed the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> shortcut was no longer working (gives the special character Ŧ instead). Neither was <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> when attempting to toggle between applications.

#### What I believe to be the issue

In the preview image of my keyboard layout I saw that <kbd>ISO Level3 Shift</kbd> was showing up where my <kbd>Alt</kbd> keys should have been (either side of <kbd>Space</kbd>). I am pretty sure this has changed since the update and is causing me the issue.

#### What I have research/tried

Unchecking ¨Any Alt¨ under ¨Key to choose the 3rd level¨ option in the advanced tab of the keyboard settings:

- Changed the preview to show <kbd>Meta/Alt</kbd> left and right keys in right place but still didn´t fix the problem
- Also introduced a few other problems

I looked into changing `xmodmap` settings but found out that this had been replaced by `xkb` in Ubuntu. Following some more research I tried opening `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/gb` and tried commenting out the ***include "level3(ralt_switch)"*** text in the corresponding sections for my layout type (Macintosh variants). This did work for re-enabling the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key functionality but my <kbd>d</kbd> key stopped working.....(but still worked on chrome if not in a us english layout).

I´ve now returned those files to the way they were and re-selected "Key to choose the 3rd level" option in the advanced tab of the keyboard settings. My <kbd>Alt</kbd> key currently is working as suspected but my <kbd>d</kbd> key doesn't work along with other issues.

Running `setxkbmap -layout gb` gets the <kbd>d</kbd> key working again but breaks the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key and swaps my <kbd>"</kbd> and <kbd>@</kbd> second options. I guess this is because it's changed basic to default english layout and I intend on using the Macintosh option.

*If anyone could help me with this issue I'd be very grateful as it's currently driving me insane.*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I am not sure which Ubuntu version and flavor you are in. However, it looks like the system is guessing your keyboard model. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` sets it precisely. I do not want to be impolite to a British man. Please don't get mad at me if this doesn't work. Honour at your service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately this does not solve my issue. My <kbd>d</kbd> key still doesn't work and I have to run `setxkbmap -layout gb` to get it work which mixes all my keys up in the wrong order for my layout. I'm wondering whether it's because I'm using a Keychron K2 keyboard which doesn't have an option in the selected models list from your suggested code. FYI I'm using Plasma by KDE flavour of Ubuntu.

Comment: I am not sure but Keychron K2 is a hybrid apple/windows layout, the reading from article on internet, the windows layout in the K2 is somewhat messy. When `dpkg-reconfigure keybo...` you should select "apple laptop" as well as selector on the left of your keyboard. The fastest way to solve this problem, ask Keychron in HK. One thing I am certain is the Right_Alt key operation in the Ubuntu/Debian is messy especially US layout. When I want to edit something near R_Alt and Modifier swap/restore, I edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` directly. eg. Make R_CTL key as R_ALT ,`<RALT> = 105`